# Web Scraping with bs4 pyhton3. Cant find elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently experimenting with BeautifulSoup(bs4) in python3.

When i go to print the soup or sauce the elements that i am looking for are not there.

I cannot find the code for this table (see screenshot of the table website) in the sauce/soup.

[image: screenshot of table from website]

Here is my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.flashscore.com/field-hockey/netherlands/hoofdklasse/standings/")

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

print(soup) # or i print r.text -> the sauce
```

Any help would be much appreciated.Please could you explain any suggestions if possible.

Comment: common problem: page uses JavaScript to add items but `BS` and `requests` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you may use DevTools in Firefox/Chrom (tab: Network, filter: XHR) to find url used by JavaScript to get data from server and then you can use this url with `requests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very, very common problem: page uses `JavaScript` to add items but `BS` and `requests` can't run `JavaScript`.

You may use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript` and use Selenium functions to search data or get HTML from Selenium (driver.page_source) and use `BS`.

OR you may use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`) to find url used by `JavaScript` to get data from server and then you can use this url with `requests`.

---

Using `DevTools` I found url and get HTML with table.

It needed header `'X-Fsign'` to get data instead of HTML with message `401 Unauthorized`

I don't know if this header always has the same value. If not then it would need more research to find this value in HTML or in Cookies.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/ss_1_INmPqO86_GOMWObX1_table_overall'

headers = {
#    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
#    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
#    'X-Referer': 'https://www.flashscore.com/field-hockey/netherlands/hoofdklasse/standings/',
    'X-Fsign': 'SW9D1eZo',
#    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
#    'Referer': 'https://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/proxy-local',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for item in soup.find_all('span', class_='team_name_span'):
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
Bloemendaal
Den Bosch
HGC
Rotterdam
Kampong
Oranje Rood
Amsterdam
Pinoke
Tilburg
Klein Zwitserland
Hurley
Almere
```

Comment: Hey @furas please could you outline how you found the url in the devtools?